# Dúvida sobre local onde declarar variável

Tags: javascript, react-native

Estou com uma consulta em um objeto que está em um componente funcional em React Native. Criei uma matriz principal (`arrayholder`) para armazenar todos os dados enquanto filtro as informações na variável de estado (clients).

Minha dúvida é a seguinte, quando declaro o `arrayholder` fora do escopo da função a mesma é preenchida com os dados corretamente, mas quando declaro dentro do escopo ela simplesmente não recebe os dados ficando um array vazio. Porque? Até então não entendi muito bem a diferença de declarar variáveis dentro ou fora do escopo do componente funcional.

Segue o código:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react'

let arrayholder = [] - quando declarada aqui fora é alimentada no loadClients

export default props => {
    const [clients, setClients] = useState([])
    const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState(false)
    const [search, setSearch] = useState(null)
    //let arrayholder = [] - quando declarada aqui dentro não é alimentada no loadClients

    useEffect(() => loadClients(), [])

    const loadClients = async () => {
        try {
            setIsLoading(true)
            const res = await axios.get(`${serverClients}?auth=${props.token}`)
            setClients(res.data)
            arrayholder = res.data //alimento aqui
            setIsLoading(false)
        } catch (e) {
            showError(e)
        }
    }

    const updateSearch = search => {
        console.warn(arrayholder) //visualizo o conteudo
    }
}
```

Comment: Se ele recebe valores e você quer manter-los nesse array, porque nao cria um estado para ele (`const [arrayholder, setArrayholder] = useState(...)`)? Da forma que você fez, declarando fora da função, acabou gerando uma closure.

Comment: Quando você faz `let arrayholder = []` dentro da função, ela _reseta_ o valor de `arrayholder` a cada re-renderização do componente. Se quer persistir os dados, crie um estado para `arrayholder`.

Comment: Oi meu amigo, me ajudando mais uma vez... kkkkkkkkkkkkk Cara, eu não criei um estado pois só queria entender o porque antes. Então quando crio uma variável dentro da função ela reseta a cada renderização? Porque? Tem algum texto sobre o assunto? E como assim da forma que eu fiz acabei gerando uma closure?Abraços